# Addclass function in jQuery not adding the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that toggles CSS class on runtime.

```
showSearchBar: function () {
    $searchBar.addClass('open');
    alert($searchBar.hasClass('open'));
    $searchBar.find('input[type="text"]').focus();
}
```

This simple function throws an alert saying `open` class is not added. I checked in browser as well, and the class seems to not be added at all. The object itself is accessible, and the function is getting called. I checked CSS as well, and the class exists. So, basically I am trying to get a hint on how to debug this problem better.

Full function:

```
var $searchBar = $('.search-bar');
$.AdminBSB.search = {
    activate: function () {
        var _this = this;
        //Search button click event
        $('.js-search').on('click', function () {
            _this.showSearchBar();
        });

        //Close search click event
        $searchBar.find('.close-search').on('click', function () {
            _this.hideSearchBar();
        });

        //ESC key on pressed
        $searchBar.find('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                _this.hideSearchBar();
            }
        });
    },
    showSearchBar: function () {
        $searchBar.addClass('open');
        alert($searchBar);
        $searchBar.find('input[type="text"]').focus();
    },
    hideSearchBar: function () {
        $searchBar.removeClass('open');
        $searchBar.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    }
}
```

Corresponding div

```
<div class="search-bar">
    <div class="search-icon">
        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="START TYPING...">
    <div class="close-search">
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Apparently the object reference is there. But if I do `$searchBar.hasClass`, it always returns false.

Comment: There's no reason that this would not work, assuming `$searchBar` is a reference to a legitimate jQuery object. Could you please add a working example of the problem to the question.

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. `addClass` is not broken. Is `$searchbar` a jQuery object containing an SVG element by any chance? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Added the full jquery function and the html. Sadly, I don't know how to create a runnable version without adding all the css.

Comment: Your logic works fine in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/zr4esnow/. Check the console for errors

Comment: I checked console. No errors at all. And funny thing is, if I create an alert for `alert($searchBar.hasClass('search-bar'))` class, it still shows false. Even though, this class is there in html itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I simply added an id instead of searching by css.

```
$.AdminBSB.search = {
activate: function () {
    var _this = this;

    //Search button click event
    $('.js-search').on('click', function () {
        _this.showSearchBar();
    });

    //Close search click event
    $('.close-search').on('click', function () {
        _this.hideSearchBar();
    });

    //ESC key on pressed
    $('#search-bar').find('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            _this.hideSearchBar();
        }
    });
},
showSearchBar: function () {
    $('#search-bar').addClass('open'); 
    $('#search-bar').find('input[type="text"]').focus();
},
hideSearchBar: function () {
    $('#search-bar').removeClass('open');
    $('#search-bar').find('input[type="text"]').val('');
}
}
```

Updated function to use ID instead of css class.

I still haven't figure out why this specific function was having difficulty finding elements by css class. But this workaround works for me.